# Monotonically increasing function and Lipschitz continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality, real-numbers

Let  $f(t,x):[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

If $$|f(t,x)-f(t,y)|\leq C|x-y|, C>0$$ (Lipschitz continuous functions).

I need to found a monotonically increasing function $g(t;x)$ on $[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}$ such that
 $$|f(t,x)-f(t,y)|^{2}\leq C\left|g(t,x)-g(t,y)\right|, x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: What do you mean by "monotonically increasing"? For each $t,$ $g(t;x)$ is increasing as a function of $x$?

Comment: A two-variable function $f(t, x)$ is called monotonically increasing
if whenever $t_{2} \geq  t_{1}$ and $x_ {2} ≥ x_{1}$ we have:             $$f(t_{2},x_{2})-f(t_{2},x_{1})-f(t_{1},x_{2})+f(t_{1},x_{1})\geq 0$$